# Why does a many to one merge join change the sort order of the data set?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan, azure-sql-data-warehouse, query-performance

I have a query that calculates `row_Number()`. The table has a clustered index on the same columns (and order) as the partitioning and ordering for the row number.

When using a merge join (many to one), a sort is required, even though the clustered index is in the correct order. Removing the join also removes the sort operation.

The clustered index that should power the row_number calculation:

```
create clustered index [ClusteredIndex_e060df3fbf464a8eb9b6ea5d46a9a5f5] on [dbo].[log1]
(
    [client] asc,
    [orderId] asc,
    [campaign] asc,
    [id] asc,
    [DateStamp] asc
)

create clustered index [ClusteredIndex_dd0ee53e050d436cba2cab7c678a39e5] on [dbo].[LiveReference]
(
    [client] asc,
    [orderId] asc,
    [campaign] asc
)
```

The query:

```
    with cr as 
(
    select distinct client, orderId,campaign
    from LiveReference
)

select e.[DateStamp]
  ,e.[campaign]
  ,e.[client]
  ,e.[orderId]
  ,e.[ad]
  ,e.[id]
  ,e.[source]
,row_number() over (partition by e.[client] ,
                        e.[orderId] ,
                        e.[campaign] ,
                        e.[id] 
                    order by e.[DateStamp]) as num
from [dbo].[log1] e 
inner join cr on 
                        e.client = cr.client
                        and e.campaign = cr.campaign
                        and e.orderId =  cr.orderId
```

which gives the below plan:
[image]

Removing the join also removes the sort:

```
select e.[DateStamp]
  ,e.[campaign]
  ,e.[client]
  ,e.[orderId]
  ,e.[ad]
  ,e.[id]
  ,e.[source]
,row_number() over (partition by e.[client] ,
                        e.[orderId] ,
                        e.[campaign] ,
                        e.[id] 
                    order by e.[DateStamp]) as num
from [dbo].[log1] e
```

(I know this also removes the filtering performed by the join, but this doesn't explain why excluding those rows changes the order)

[image]

Why would the results of a sorted join then not be in the correct order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, merge join (including merge join concatenation) only preserves the sort order of the join keys.

The merge join keys are `client, campaign, orderId`. The required input sort order for the window function is `client, orderId, campaign, id , datestamp`.

The merge join cannot therefore provide the sort order required by your window function. You could avoid the sort with a nested loops join (e.g. using a hint).

[image: nested loops plan]

I wrote about the details in [Avoiding Sorts with Merge Join Concatenation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

The query can be rewritten as,

```
select e.[DateStamp]
  ,e.[campaign]
  ,e.[client]
  ,e.[orderId]
  ,e.[ad]
  ,e.[id]
  ,e.[source]
,row_number() over (partition by e.[client] ,
                        e.[orderId] ,
                        e.[campaign] ,
                        e.[id] 
                    order by e.[DateStamp]) as num
from [dbo].[log1] e 
where exists(select 1 from LiveReference
 cr where
                        e.client = cr.client
                        and e.campaign = cr.campaign
                        and e.orderId =  cr.orderId
)
```

So no need of `CTE` and `distinct`